# .count() occurrences within range() in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple question that I couldn't find a answer to, maybe I'm just stupid and not searching the right stuff but here is the code.

```
list = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,10,10]
ranges = [range(1, 3), range(3, 6), range(6, 10)]

rangesCount = []

for i in ranges:
     rangesCount.append(list.count(i))


 print(rangesCount)
```

Basically I want it to count the occurrences of numbers in a certain range. So the printed output should be [3, 5, 9]

Comment: don't name your variable `list`, you're over-riding the built-in

Comment: Also note `range(6, 10)` does **not** include `10`.

Comment: Is the list of numbers always sorted?

Answer (score 0):

`list.count` is used to count occurrences of a **specified value** in a list, not to check for inclusion in `range` objects.

One solution is to use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
L = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,10,10]
ranges = [range(1, 3), range(3, 6), range(6, 10)]

rangesCount = []
for rng in ranges:
    rangesCount.append(sum(x in rng for x in L))

print(rangesCount)
# [3, 5, 7]
```

More efficient algorithms are available, e.g. `bisect`, as well as vectorised solutions via 3rd party libraries, e.g. `np.digize` [NumPy], `pd.cut` [Pandas].

Answer (score 0):

The `.count` method cannot count ranges, only values

You can easily build a range counter using a nice thing called `map`:

```
l = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9,10,10]
list(map(l.count, range(2,4)))
>> [2, 1]
sum(map(l.count, range(2,4)))
>> 3
```

Then nest it in a for loop:

```
list(sum(map(l.count, x) )for x in (range(1, 3), range(3, 6), range(6, 10)))
>> [3, 5, 7]
```